# How to change the color of the default JProgressBar?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, colors, jprogressbar

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 and I am trying to change the color of the JProgressBar from the default orange as shown below:

[image]

I have tried changing the foreground and background in the properties but the result does nothing except change the color of the text inside the bar, but keeps the color of the bar itself orange.

When I try to manually code the JProgressBar it has more of a 2D appearance as shown below:

[image]

How can I change the color of the JProgressBar but also keep the 3D textured style of the default JProgressBar or is not possible?

Comment: The 3D effect is a feature of the Look & Feel.

Comment: But how do I implement it with a different color for the bar other than orange?

Comment: @Osiris93 You don't. Or you completely override the components UI your self.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Ok how would I override these components or where can I find resources on doing so?

Comment: @Osiris93 Have a look at "MadProgrammer's" answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908135/how-to-customize-a-jprogressbar)

Comment: @DimaMaligin Thank you, that seems to do what I have been looking to do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//this changes color
pb.setForeground(new Color(r,g,b)); 

//this changes textcolor
pb.setUI(new BasicProgressBarUI() {
                protected Color getSelectionBackground() { return Color.black; }
                protected Color getSelectionForeground() { return Color.white; }
            });
```

I've tested it in metal look and feel and with nimbus

pb is a JProgressBar object.