# Custom JProgress Bar

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I'm trying to create a custom JProgressbar but i'm having no luck. The way I'm trying to do is it to create extending my class with JProgressBar but I can't seem to get the border right.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the related code, otherwise is impossible to help you.

Comment: So, you want it square? You want the text displayed? You want the color changed? If you don't want to write your own from scratch, one of the better places to start is with the `BasicProgressBarUI` - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908135/how-to-customize-a-jprogressbar/28909255#28909255)