# How to add a canvas on progress bar using java swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want overlay  canvas on progress bar.Please find the below image:
I have created a progress bar and i have created a canvas. but i was not getting any info how to overlay canvas on progress bar as shown in image

[image]

```
    //program for horizontal progress bar
public class Progress extends JFrame {

    // create a frame
    static JFrame f;

    static JProgressBar b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        f = new JFrame("ProgressBar demo");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        b = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        b.setValue(0);

        b.setStringPainted(true);
        p.add(b);
        f.add(p);
        b.add(new SwingDemo());

        // set the size of the frame
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}




//code for canvas
```

Comment: Please tell the details of what exactly you mean by "overlay a canvas on a progress bar"

Comment: means we have  to insert canvas on progress bar as shown in the link. i have created a progress bar and canvas separately. but i need to insert canvas on progress bar

Comment: Again, what do you mean "canvas on progress bar"? The picture shows the progress bar sitting on a canvas (or other container), the opposite of what you're requesting, not the canvas *on* the progress bar.

Comment: no .a rectangular box (canvas) which is marked with red color is sitting on progress bar.how can we achieve that using swing.any idea?

Comment: Ah, I get you now. That is useful information and should be placed in your question, I think. If this were my application, I'd just create my own component that draws the bar and the image, and moves it along similar to a scroll bar's scrollbox.

Comment: Could you please give me idea, so that i can work on it

Comment: Better still, have a look at MadProgrammer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28909255/522444). It is truly beautiful (1+)